# Python local datetime month

Tags: python, datetime

I have a python TZ-aware datetime `end_date` of, say 2013-03-01 06:00:00+00:00.  I want to get the month of this datetime for the America/Chicago timezone.  If I do `end_date.month` I get 3.  I'd like to make a method call something like `end_date.timezone('America/Chicago').month` -- or something -- that would give me the correct value of 2.

Thought I understood this datetime/pytz stuff...

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `pytz.timezone('America/Chicago').localize(end_date).month`?

Comment: Nice try, but this gives: ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)

Comment: I guess `end_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')).month`?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Although technically the month is still 3 as 2013-03-01 06:00:00+00:00 is 2013-03-01 00:00:00 CST-0600 -- but I can deal with that.  Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer that goes into a little bit more depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.astimezone()` (and according to the docs, to handle timezone transitions and things like daylight savings, you should `.normalize()` the result).

```
from pytz import timezone
end_date = ...tz-aware datetime...
us_tz = timezone('America/Chicago')

localized_end_date = us_tz.normalize(end_date.astimezone(us_tz))
```

Note that `.astimezone` cannot be used with a naive datetime - it must be a TZ-aware datetime. The alternative is to use the `.localize()` method on the `tzinfo` instance.

```
end_date = ...naive datetime...
localized_end_date = timezone('America/Chicago').localize(end_date, is_dst=None)
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Correct - thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: set `is_dst=None` if you want to raise an exception for ambiguous naive datetimes instead of possibly incorrect (50%) `is_dst=True` or `is_dst=False`. Though if only `.month` is interesting then it is better to suppress the exception.